# How to ignore eslint rule for a specific computer

Tags: javascript, git, eslint

Our project specifies the `linebreak-style` rule to be `"unix"`. Nevertheless, some developers use Windows with automatic conversion to CRLF and we would like to keep that as it is for now. Is it possible to disable the `linebreak-style` rule (or set it to `"windows"`) on their computers in such a way that this configuration is not shared with the main repository (i.e., not visible to git)?

Comment: Alternative: remove the rule entirely and write a pre-commit hook that verifies only Unix-style linebreaks are used.

Comment: Another alternative: I believe most modern IDEs/text editors can be customized to just use specific linebreak characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `--skip-worktree` to avoid git checking for changes to a configuration file.

Ex: `git update-index --skip-worktree path\to\.eslintrc.json`

You could optionally combine this with the [extends functionality](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-a-configuration-file) in the eslint configuration file(s) such that one configuration file has your base/shared configurations and a git-ignored configuration file can have local changes applied. This approach should help you keep most of the eslint rules shared via git.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool that can enable different rules for different platforms. It can do this by providing different `.eslintrc.json` on windows and other platforms.

Here is an example of using different `cypress.zip` depending on Windows or Linux:

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-cypress

And here is an example using that approach:

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-cypress-example